# Problema de codificación en aplicación de consola de c# - no se muestran caracteres especiales en terminal integrada de Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, vscode, consola, utf-8

Estoy aprendiendo c#, creando aplicaciones de consola.
El entorno es el sdk de .net 8 y Visual Studio Code como editor de código con las extensiones de c#.
Tengo el siguiente código:

```
Console.WriteLine("¿Cuál es tu nombre?");
string nombre = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine($"Hola {nombre}!");
```

Al ejecutarlo con la terminal integrada de Vs Code, se visualiza así:

> dotnet run
> C:\Users\Username\CsharpProjects\TestProject\Program.cs(2,17): warning
> CS8600: Se va a convertir un literal nulo o un posible valor nulo en
> un tipo que no acepta valores NULL
> [C:\Users\Username\CsharpProjects\TestProject\TestProject.csproj]
> ¿Cuál es tu nombre? Nicolás Hola Nicols! PS
> C:\Users\Username\CsharpProjects\TestProject>

El problema es que aparentemente la tilde de "Nicolás" no se guarda en la variable nombre, ya que la terminal muestra correctamente los acentos, tanto al leerlos (primer Console.WriteLine) como al enviarlos.
Lo mismo pasa con otros caracteres especiales como 'ñ'.
Probé ejecutar el mismo código desde un Powershell externo y los caracteres se muestran bien.
Probé añadir las siguientes líneas de código al inicio del archivo, pero no solucionaron el problema:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Console.InputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Probé ejecutar el mismo script pero en Python y las tildes y otros caracteres espciales se muestran correctamente.

Muchas gracias,
saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con este código:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(nombre);
nombre = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Se guarda en un **arreglo de bytes** la codificación de cada carácter de la cadena, y posteriormente este **arreglo de bytes** se vuelve a convertir en texto.

Finalmente tu código quedaría así:

```
Console.WriteLine("¿Cuál es tu nombre?");

string nombre = Console.ReadLine();
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(nombre);

nombre = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine($"Hola {nombre}!");
```

**Actualización**:

Cambia la codificación de la consola a **Unicode**:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Console.InputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
```

Prueba también a cambiar la fuente que utiliza la consola, ya que por defecto esta utiliza el **tipo de fuente Consolas**, el cual no admite ciertos caracteres, para hacer esto das clic derecho en la barra de título de la consola, seleccionas la opción propiedades y ahí escoges otro tipo de fuente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero no ha funcionado. Es extraño, parece que directamente no llegan los caracteres especiales al programa, pese a que la terminal los soporte. Si escribo un echo con caracteres especiales se muestran bien

Comment: @Marcos revisa lo nuevo que puse

Comment: muchas gracias, cambiando la codificación de la consola a unicode los acentos se muestran correctamente, tanto en la terminal integrada de Vscode como en terminales externas. Alguna idea de por qué sucede esto? teniendo en cuenta que en terminales externas funciona sin esa modificación, y que en otros lenguajes la terminal integrada funciona correctamente. Alguna configuración o valor que se pueda cambiar para que funcione por defecto?